# Convert a decimal to picture

Tags: adafruit

I used Arduino Uno3 to commute with camera VC0706 adafruit ,I captured a picture then I read picture's data from camera via UART and that is a long decimal sequence about 25000 characters but the picture's sizes is larger than 45000bytes .I know the size because I send a command to get picture's size to camera.

This is the decimal sequence :

```
1180500025521625525403651172162700000000000000022411282605018118148140025521901320211111211122222422222533345566566610910119102224965699999999999999999999950172241231960110004711311101481112512188134145662136114102538425458697284879910210611712113213313413513613713814614714814915015115215315416216316416516616716817818118519820121121521822823123424424924742176113145519852385367728699105119131136149162170185200215230245250255221040402552180022211811413813825315321615432194211245240304114551201967023766200124126224925114676106733615511842047020428158104223142041410810550236129203532162313663203561692059159792502521508520317522815260210979822275163316610553271231961832001002181358012322819933313331147106791424351181791661571545023051144220562301221195197183247207247715717086112177464920810919699561161511581652092291027414424868130135185511567164631660162176167174119998925224257201571481088314710711525510553681361649181572452071591281541692292043020281412910815419815621911291212243150142492181671201281452292130120167228669670582441561232774120109262125991172731091931547249961541741491222119213824119811249197107207512542003628212192157862151291968123261332579249208204180611201762816118420119959881187974252587181229291492441646725917841206921491552192115610324962172392132369621220241017316914147230106531271193822278231230757180411879020931951206924212021197185195138189712439623562123579323917921141682124281921151616110711092175742451358145473511339138117206761311321521077131291919414512826019321112557166646791223114781661192151401992201702251121691319332141554019616412332071744118713112382337227102131130160171481820011021611124757201110303224975522208622812089210979153402322820466126951521132082371691651325108149149247233250124177232299217243212211084813192831411452014375128775724716910124112741239814712519724515415272230115911341651496134136192153165043752211553811523323514720320418948119271466819646112122267723699317164961911141031427714611136793195601156222917752158491102855514572301535614622183150393930190148219826937113143822422823133167911337223115651727128217664424108121432181842472441414124414217215619914115128121341466665194158163165111761099041392371972162302322723218491691792522112275817312713995147131061432211972385474913714911923922615739181252220158121572124234198744113920708121215623616722624284157240140191648514814825131829122221629126149454317818017642078215815446201369207106261003912199242801761149661531091987614913157701435411423913420618792132162770105744116121713313122618170132191180201169128165119924761184100722171672152297761199152250247173132491421642181652351707117177165720124562261126510520221624473024980217213534812212820424523977168174981831512222466313258272100110199714492472356919304597011018214932491332112132395514716423712911821131981281642644222718569226132271471471472151561131291285922815420928252211886018217044484424479192189173233249751901072245331871642431602171652311382491961976716159720016123218021144224707219181841228672101761061552292473510176107523112201148169222244341332513423315217615610356301341542241721411285719869159791463623133879131251122142163638792330199314216513598202546650408768123811191412534139166161204196801051831421564315817520022010183652818224519919751741172291821731432833115168115101922422142152921612412918624378147102172216810877181118133751621831471761692101962482501554521825164193198105261843611564993316536233116170919861211624910923261214120242234101982101561182401458910790246190170205831971691192313816220215322124910561471342072032352221354369144127687156203982271362061651981703721381332920465351131991651001642491541102412165314125145913118726702092422301640164901212301571071145110983522519813824919451165148271181291196811520522815018436192961252202418418011312299319299150145120140969227244292826731721055814611265154230021915110908012148252201201205225122154197970631161071411816918510510512141601921329542203724729781518521617111127139119167320411223993203597612517663128235916219248961591551817343198227104961251151525213661154136432150203255715824411912058142216179202372019114623672522542271731822579160314080100215210926197711442211732182096181462041351211942356481925823278245271096271221801301172421842271682910538254185878352427755472121102211704124211351905213791021052101406091642142302112331402111592141367183142401844123112231242541445617662817129244812222185198191521235219639135254179717929222322541187068222232342454117413046220114419222676200886313315410514616021023161781211842522271741614516511896351331415113615317194223182131777074246161497351312451677422592142207178142412425712541261791921593901918416702358241196812818920823871135151551741832154121135724316720001521801678521214124124148175271420120012417166511543087571149140186616113120519512819214031581052109620249198723171184183116212229156238165110212325912761221566713146136109107161216246494218181158244421951441931251691012189222411621711501042291492518202147722494041226978319114670568350391671101235717317711224865141251143101125692051251336614120233239784418421914111521021123914616825025253243154188109156022121329548422416066621286524375702134352352552132521585722228122946311210536155205212332274116427793922271469261249251160224720921314813152701984141185179239795724312224112812918620623199244230708981178148112110501653130771832273310423516317717096592211090102157131138872478316324222815816718322418424317161401049101157182100255614716522112245791408045122192364561772373021125116412325121115616982151101137323915714019224619162991336615594961472251881222183531501802281039180579123564313811842146918119153186762673216711012923021698165129170239240792247919421718417112924411375571162101471852004817021630702216223856980121233722361651371489230103651101535901511618919247025223312515722410101082425759322252082351992024417025223310222925031332064215473618761991132434129220165169165156571512278706719817611142212467132218236253420220065163105101442071451921922001665619611125236224489618722112714819866581501462792292512328741481797423917113811141041271708820923232988199921131541461026020025421688135191228229242331701713192222119591115217183187122723464423312224715525114818167142222244179301301561381310423821710810615710128169253161866310259209241121751581741282596110204472492191951741011221313150711994212174631207222220919821240241261445524723815023379113224137228144187701017287142314116723812810718075152921941747415915530148178542152141371942321042141432542391577012118010112214928132221282031281152181865734198250421547513012157599685455345240192251472092292101879770138219858525014405910638255167487510752272012520421721397741527092165119918119764318764942275774156192203018316711810916117371271991143617327167219175541566421442741047026152351235614225518574583157232121915811886661862622344129101387325424622287237431652520021678113225177194254127877581453257494920128197202126965422782153356237199214165153179331942400207618916823018043146214541381811212616323715579213323219122165228355298110210197911947977734116991291922261492501775398108198497024116147161333309716713412863252217562624621889451231402191191561771782424418517720790732004721117619325242148250147222366519879105812431991667632171412387321070203129192146159050137125907901875625167621213230128116170731602330566821810684245917042146147448517854156201941501796218711343453678328467181184822166562241977171105112119197214154237143511318938155252155105412917714816721281581420944165175156214301792518585187200220224158492112101551892442714213121019722824116415017834797021364014118014415318618905188198122423613219820414620602272162015099244235681705119932252250795815619912181192143551138140752111051711641610943116451931039922981391592495414410510220014414956242014815926146451611997476179902252251166522720518319919281113281411452149211167184203192841521723469661111491655230222481067346272082192112181731166313421221143205106244185179200113290179110521735322722252431812096671502345884194902341419623112920016211422714733210231148227132401932174432381351125310812051982165921221414431981891252331791823619323913183100227197392118191199140169168732002212231551531038836811401192222111807215483145171591465923014817724350797154236690176112211861715619218668126748184149291646622451650177841171102301622062011510198157388914210536186143723317012213797732824719573181282253314521623523911362128155175619301362527203068116141211244189249227213616495636241220251837391791823959162562311382154823122783180215020991582407111217313212811814322312182032162441651511421132191381262372211291982301764818614311822262133187116069391528323349524212918103198188183816411922197169210491851572441761361961221233233559018723210592104148250432548119912022818362642081571871824219471246191362151181388652421691146310363162113216821652291371051151471948839361142444122416423512771382796517120424510511170182168425735243162112601922341231165211919925243385616321201211567541417212980109183462020449827680160462411492354313517617948236113197921822134212444823513820799792449888187118108100150252167107130190220114742061291672201209552581971716716330563242165272326312222811012212891641381711401444219228612092301871195716108164201363018762101216107237244318775718920948642181602241001471024693581590136205212251601381381871883191122619214327168732570145192105812251140233233205821761072045318614568156622432183310921910397100129158312232051619316020235119229152208010516215220953227177611631952212401771642923568231452421452397156118189362057714028188210125420223820615811222864151399322419021219714318107141611335423716067414015625113818318611421023162741141857516211618569251684112235571281844025522814170241572252311314861839120811923468273629220962471921198327164149592311902491183255182194148210854125016521216971951164601953874454525122243878201292481022061142291042499320515881219276126232244720482201024314279115811249499510622445244116954152957549251342381813620412910711972052474211621625439122163961088714120621111918317243122612251061363522611014519522478881571601271590150174195166164414916725517228225247819189782126714812937137218147144115163112283121662233141911762151132008718723019104321235200197581252176112057111447864120152211561620192101831524455412419931974201231189323329243183192121418023824917413974128232246209343223610221998146811316580158215355192011325015514892134245693929108146382279531221224154116193124226642324125513156676325123724981822952912991227297114922113182131045817125024615371156183295921217465125223236121254141891569617347190836327642391461475017513055157167224103193891401602141114517381673187248130187136255010012380183177106542492201912262111871079323743238814112916982961507614057159181701452081182024716922411319820522365184159255214252153220662448527913018215618883165991491582331092272511259146411472101465296220141639105352922112065716913951141132081013536159175151112203901875924471952421169020244140230227751881442374821478180842441352279612685909423678902171361851251749611519703210512712214420710515621525158113100180111123010975147132377325519341541194015424781154216104113140238205621771021421431924410816519649735123314925172192249124218224205606119812523313316513115118173881392041951092431222122065576184174102163110521371472001304154281094018741901446184129180137223161180123571291551142261641513623731833816223323818014820514122174189492151874324722785123665821551121101309814625222614014124613624978362013119582236162931632461341355315179622269719510620614111846063321404321167231762402516227563488331151441068225137207108981413615526232582224124810258244219846174155123789851132614248229113110104612421281522121114113219252128214237519614014789162491091731359022122011386621096529548419987039190131506210525213010220615128811223712323432108231112562272079179204236711951407425054147257316923930362001571711738219915219311222052655189711385675501621591949111942189231191901241644319541772248673192289877571131821378513580183250481071131654617524322791164171240972385681191041394998963633613321102451409116315512624719350161112156152239176449017547311994312101981958725523323017635608314343162261978712979148156118112272201816972512813519918923140147631946181252249821608113562547417943261365671571631736352532171412496420724733202916411035381651891832171951462224728913524925320090147205751438919246232189181711734519902199145212811023618058165207244336249118138812392052454521710784211841547220213244471255157138149281842816119823971281852024988491997647135140201561262185211142369621673108161214120481876112825224443212292471101051471025819472242445630227521471842382081381821641991420396118177171092514115112579356523111617219189921701691871932121722372001984518816410188822051462291132192019624211395531291133616912715114224917114369552052442341052371838829276619266196751591641252071895893171401942461642362446124411309943751793276205921311802415517010210114351232220362720727317316413456165144962442013219249822139613111023673219134823220207060172255119102122195902061061991092192212282151082021901201512317223211181588610163431151409813021701131767516910918220227211791895317458126781744417016025167972614520612320715911019624529187212132191601571423723325218915622456212131250229249421254173873222023118082167731817714513167190658171081147190124132130860981362371884182161169129391601559623560112292522189142149232157571419322517615883120842761639421217524718215856251691861231877391952081572311771541149121397625067235213242242252512512142431284532242197613317543368324712161120226164113206151183856795928831288070186165112985241671791031531802816321541292351421641865810619219323768236851183072226156852372381451171929409612313017192129147958528170884710618439815351152161772581129231244242155232106671547310448156553613123377254115252186251611451791241823037148201112171462465994197720717436141621136211310916515217413622314513112851192162240214841331712252243920281579627247722516715411525319252105217244221314140252714921685113156304123918024214980252389134132498225217713118441107352184315269201109103181631462222482382531501738200196677199331372057338214148224130216166491617369921462111102117414911501062011428065222206192165201341931543186110250113111723011632172441971424618792491982076488516318973545318813412451268726281542122201357426143200251017312817321197111120990707920178167334313018377548711552371551082161592275923639125281449844239146110112172245240134583139204191204253481181077169108101246134198256215524193712322001101052331169629168198481901602718282165167226224992184154934722416414772212391601991101871122091521265918522822910766392121566067226130631642118661628413862235015416415423314713810621499712212512176014784015627792531571961068713623518131013857116411491812333114515814219975971482123410110115310151129138124234232901611771323478209491292002321661842921962371492102033916682918216110683122125246198074678875313113814684301022261151922021118119112592272291668518514927696016773212221621567616080127236252169242366226185531992431920021459212511051111831711211910524217322179184256519156165199504096102062929201140174209109641202416621411214105179178221146238200949620412523475961903226822501693524535157141528411995612422032257146207916516717217895178133736176198151602319918157166592461458210819224916416019492362272724388165363129109252198186144161129142173192184825673612041212075218301503624523319920885758454158177155125112852819814825125221115320320219973421472385032282507244236192221661763524217022113931879192325887157473320718514199206016216613939193721242312101641027165164177151684015922986323125502137920792141631298917281138182570185228417911112813422415614013167841912117021110014528176255202144247166821392302317021115619810001523810580233197567122910022389582471791082121011922116820122122717418124457169182206645111620167738867204020023915840153207156197146246617148551992081848324012911036761702204201911231638490229198189173108150188418222202224206225222218093161581411716421499151422268672561322136311610017891903623217882334166462289281179822311821721215998220213112020082191216245311311922111432028113914223184571148396241021254114049236289420718116792867851066917518413611222049381678720322252448724419810874564878143102491498617533446116011980702022431733616814592120662117317451981352022282541162191941502218180177169159821701365522017614254812247219554253112238154248131198142822380222566012222616415913401561763142931601161981447516912193203631262452818388218282839231321561891442361891921681598075674441401991451582222453811977130144301581561352121172271431410651086144461671561491939984233995416910186197786824833337230391105716412013912134829124789101702210942223512016114314914911925885241462331931689617067134351842523521920691731463716177202151221082510501172041995825140112445388254181661191131949683140512322481606425219217418578616519918182739218718792107592273611717011635641062392101933861161219255170120178156408222072171220313868352417224945234149652142251713312714995701041461215144291408721100136591872495813042491387511511619510888158122116169981612242241005112016710316513818218217737147541712002551211641192048612919014323924220924598104154146227212711133131621691893159244197308311312913820519723445902411314718706414919720812218197271562001652101461181225472167114282141321508287561252671082119720536185774419816114110110818222824474242193751332487113613826245222271329111622123896205151642058724523194125204521285108231229207951671832154424610610087216227146321764149102371138657113413612042386711068732371101673891131651512384720515815771832492522351802151021002167920416410613524315152171831302191992512312146146140157122147187646154942485662253512398220314121735361751461921662222017111821922724992219243156184255188224612532173136213782261216013022214718566110576098159412031090250153615023919823324274233144195248911133184221153206143138166819862253741561322811846178229107222222071142313790988792181153166771972111321272920756102318715925872191581761698110316794213791061787820072112324119744188542248163142239238245117209392224922314217813311311721314824722717320692741292101151315916016625424343144652524214622814751127186492088718025537140878715012122823510416715319887154225150237113196199149662372096611320051868282230216198236132203229200921731284315020622272701979961220186742196114523612210817423010421901493298216239201217185125227351305141111618180129771135922121629814467120731062091437217424523361623556561721241186124313617723172101461182491768614973149242451589681129129214201211442122921457167121532051402272216123410983169223105192981591285414362812222501298017025114118982426542140242109202821842223912362542072011473352197555786621016234134217120224148240499074206204811051661361962482282469645169211511718245113224162211032130228192434324046541121835773662161218339331822276313574124132118201271141431188715814857149227145229312017536117221202101103121120313021259311618442611396219249133224254201633920510240243492212035701421842069614566227159108351150166741294169254262523313916757592272046714010924311514679959663165791962371825221222237194174242991067045901394516922244166222231221152181695712323723015402219161020160852191602112201542736632190185181401044913417243932465479471051561481411562031683674227357811925164716122209119542261125912981791502482271182018313334211659963232112236315625116611839416017711821587172178218862296220621582442197423917020158233312552203566561814617621111323579242130702511762303271171574260192180142237546731761962037070799012521316710913113394148947514724043651931721972241482002232107319213521022715320531071082071054820124242250244529564571325025501416210562046317649160216143217281332812741461122227810081141931631189012898100427949436518021113831741821110710069121372314812013621071441751276122872254107822051821522341302357916723810421379245409951732816422083411191153215821325413211378105152451127434247147254216422401517214571111814158801451251433641227163227821731451012542127723618511641751111653719613214818816311515399344177311758117617117161751548992339319818419123310717924130122169142532347322933915610801851202182262191621564134156178122216112515941236962211131514615324051303523021338024477711051791810622783735291862095417311422924180189711114017924999292383910701671322531281281998635253217230235104218901772202388114612224173612274124924744190199721641782011461711072331460687871193801539156462867159127231311931821552055714428625372309127136171382249016419215392207215159143233253119101322485710422712828903732551376021075119150142250255049863524367146842532061152471985214125022422296625618416616862147981102192095612514829119692103619055111702212412419497341826594722442121108133361561781722273145781571379316112586316758431240158224122882431581705513106724662192359124217319515421819272304238231110117147523193241205160749422936127168222163371871068411324020881071252017016853752441121381601562241215216116167188176115255184066138103123234812414512210014602155657255136235228158216121251495179462106341211314813422814015167781061331555217213916323623321218943482225402411982316910823117013514282018021222724721144249652271913179243239791481275224018113120252190653622411313118019222784240182123194197515221106161112139181182421931091971831162471711822314514208253202722446118144503879115159142012361252249189231325053158161692071286347245131157312032002272191541559310695436872151734152121944157102981842425356169160651248214612157105218248220135172211513862769391851994156073235156153901431481291723857145591951088321618226125164252120237158411882118376169914715172363825224521542422722941302328282392811613838146111493113811115348156137241124138188632012514709819215999158164116229243243177317423433150166228812461271924398175230129152629481255010566195760244310611018569217121157811342184167220821742111223401641959910541271552191512320395352241281261881078140222200157100772541412321261999199119242961049619116772421871121976418215881253153566519816019615867159200239881042131131931107965232120166179209244221582322172002585232131241739312215629219207241782512613313525511805000
```

I don't know how to convert that numbers to the picture :(

This is link about camera's infomation : https://learn.adafruit.com/ttl-serial-camera?view=all

This is my sketch for TTL camera:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial cam(2,3); // RX, TX

uint8_t *READ(const int timeout,uint8_t arr[])
{
int i = 0;
long int time = millis();

while( (time+timeout) > millis())
{
  while(cam.available())
  {
     arr[i] = cam.read(); // save value into a array
    i++;
  }  
}
   return arr;
}
void setup() {
  pinMode(13,OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(13,LOW);
  cam.begin(38400);
  Serial.begin(38400);

  //GETVSion

  byte message1[] = {86,0,17,0};// {0x56,0x00,0x11,0x00};
  cam.write(message1,sizeof(message1));
  delay(300);

  //ReSume Frame

  byte message2[] = {86,0,54,1,3}; // {0x56,0x00,0x36,0x01,0x03};
  cam.write(message2,sizeof(message2));
  delay(300);  

  //STop Frame
  byte message3[] = {86,0,54,1,0};
  cam.write(message3,sizeof(message3));
  delay(300);

  //Get length for ready to capture

  byte message4[] = {86,0,52,1,0}; // {0x56,0x00,0x34,0x01,0x00};
  cam.write(message4,sizeof(message4));

  uint8_t *arr;
  uint8_t x[35];
  arr = READ(1000,x);  // read and print to serial monitor from CAMERA 
  // which return of Getvs,Resume,Stop and Get is 16 + 5 + 5 + 9 = 35 byte
  // then

 // image length are 4 bytes includes : 0 0 a b
   for(int i = 0 ; i<35;i++)   // print a b because 2 first bytes usually = 0
   { Serial.print(*(arr+i));
   Serial.print(" ");
   }

  Serial.print("\n");
  delay(300);


    // READ IMAGE
   byte message5[] = {0x56,0x00,0x32,0x0c,
                      0x00,0x0A,0x00,0x00,
                      0x00,0x00,0x00,*(arr+32),
                      *(arr+33),*(arr+34),0x0b,0xb8};
   cam.write(message5,sizeof(message5));

  while(1)
  {
    if(cam.available())
    Serial.print(cam.read());
    }

    }

void loop() 
{ }
```

Comment: have you tried `cam.readPicture(decimalResult)`?

Comment: No :3 i coded for myself , let me add my code , i forgot ^^